# NSXMLParser and parse always returns NO

Tags: php, ios, xml, nsxmlparser

After several tutorials I have read, I am trying to create my own class in order to retrieve xml results from PHP requests and use their element in my iOS app.

So I have XMLParse.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{

    NSString* url;
    NSXMLParser* parser;
    NSMutableString* element;
}

- (id) initXML: (NSString*)_url;

@end
```

and the XMLParse.m

```
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation XMLParser{

    NSXMLParser* xmlParser;
    NSMutableArray* xmlOutputData;
    NSMutableString* xmlOutputNode;

}

- (id) initXML:(NSString *)_url{

    NSLog(@"initXML\n");
    url = _url;

    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

    if ([xmlParser parse]) {
        printf("YES");
    } else{
        printf("NO");
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
     attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    NSLog(@"Started Element %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"]) {

        if (!xmlOutputData) {

            xmlOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            NSString* status = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"success"];

            if ([status isEqualToString:@"TRUE"]) {
                return;
            } else{
                printf("ERROR");
            }

        }
    }

}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    [xmlOutputNode appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                 [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"username"]) {

        NSLog(@"%@", xmlOutputNode);
    }

    xmlOutputNode = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
}

@end
```

Finally from my MenuView.m I'm initialising an object of XMLParse class

```
XMLParser* newParser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXML:@"http://localhost/conquestOfLancaster/login.php?username=test&password=1234"];
```

and the output on screen it looks like,

```
2012-12-01 18:58:50.020 CoL[2363:c07] initXML
2012-12-01 18:58:50.030 CoL[2363:1b03] ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY: http://localhost/conquestOfLancaster/login.php?username=test&password=1234
NO
```

I can't understand what I am missing and always the parse is FALSE. Can anyone help?

UPDATE:

The problem was that my result from PHP link was not a real XML output (has the structure and that confused me). Is my first try with PHP and that's the reason. I will search how you can generate an XML output from a PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is that 'ADDRESPONSE' log coming from?

Comment: does it even get valid xml into the parser? before parse, NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]);

Comment: Hello, I don't know where ADDRESPONSE coming from. This log doesn't appear each time I'm running the app, so I have no idea. Now I'm printing what you suggesting and the result is, &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;?&gt;
&lt;root success=&quot;TRUE&quot;&gt;&lt;username&gt;toto&lt;/username&gt;&lt;/root&gt; Seems like the xml from my php request. My url is valid, tested on browser.

Comment: Update: found this post, http://stackoverflow.com/a/422704/1848025 . Facing the same issue?